# Purpose of ActionName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the benefit of setting an alias for an action method using the "ActionName" attribute? I really don't see much benefit of it, in providing the user the option to call an action method with some other name. After specifying the alias, the user is able to call the action method only using the alias. But if that is required then why doesn't the user change the name of the action method rather then specifying an alias for it?

I would really appreciate if anyone can provide me an example of the use of "ActionName" in a scenario where it can provide great benefit or it is best to use.

Comment: The most common reason is when you have both GET and POST methods and the signature is the same.  see @Carlos Muñoz answer

Answer (score 139, accepted):

*It allows you to start your action with a number or include any character that .net does not allow in an identifier.* - The most common reason is it allows you have two Actions with the same signature (see the GET/POST Delete actions of any scaffolded controller)

For example: you could allow dashes within your url action name `http://example.com/products/create-product` vs `http://example.com/products/createproduct` or `http://example.com/products/create_product`.

```
public class ProductsController {

    [ActionName("create-product")]
    public ActionResult CreateProduct() {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: It also lets you use action names that might be methods on `Controller`, like View or File.

Comment: @gram, can't we call a normal method on a controller without specifying an alias? I think we can.

Comment: If you wanted to name your `Action` `View()` then you'd have problems because all references to `View()` in your current controller would resolve to that `Action` rather than the underlying base method. So to get around this you would use the `ActionName` attribute to allow for the `View` action but internally you'd call it `PublicView` or something similar.

Comment: I think you'll have to `return View("CreateProduct")` or .NET will nag about not finding a view such as `create-product.aspx` or `create-product.cshtml` -- At least my code works like this.

Comment: @gram So how do you do that? Obviously not with an attribute.

Answer (score 62):

It is also useful if you have two Actions with the same parameter list and return type, differing only in method name but that should have the same ActionName.

A simple example:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ...
}

[ActionName("SomeAction")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeActionPost()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but in what scenarios do you use HttpPost without parameters? I know there are possible reasons, like returning JSON and avoiding security issues with GET. I'm just wondering what yours is.

Comment: The parameter list is not the important part here. There might be a better example, the point is that you can do it if you need to.

Comment: we can do that by replacing "SomeActionPost" to "SomeAction" also, then what is the use of ActionName??

Comment: You can&#39;t name both methods the same if they have the same parameters. In this case [ActionName] renames the action (not the method) as registered in ASP. NET MVC route table to the intended one.

Comment: A very late comment, but I think the beginning of this answer is conflicting with the rest. You cannot have two c# methods with the same signature, i.e. return type, method name and parameters. So you're forced to change the name of one.  "if you have two Actions with the same signature" is therefore not a valid situation that can arise. I think what is meant is "if you have two methods that differ only in name and you need a single URL to expose them as actions, then you can use ActionName attribute" This answer is both helpful and confusing at the moment :)

Answer (score 39):

I use it when the user downloads a report so that they can open their csv file directly into Excel easily.

```
[ActionName("GetCSV.csv")]
public ActionResult GetCSV(){
    string csv = CreateCSV();
    return new ContentResult() { Content = csv, ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, ContentType = "text/csv" };
}
```

Comment: That is very clever :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public class ProductsController
 {

    [ActionName("create-product")]
    public ActionResult CreateProduct() 
    {
        return View("CreateProduct");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also helpful when you need to implement method overloading.

```
 public ActionResult ActorView()
        { 

            return View(actorsList);
        }


        [ActionName("ActorViewOverload")]
        public ActionResult ActorView(int id)
        {              
            return RedirectToAction("ActorView","Home");
        }
`
```

Here one ActorView accepts no parameters and  the other accepts int.
 The first method used for viewing actor list and the other one is used for showing the same actor list after deleting an item with ID as 'id'.
 You can use action name as 'ActorViewOverload' whereever you need method overloading.

Answer (score 1):

This class represents an attribute that is used for the name of an action. It also allows developers to use a different action name than the method name.