# Action name different to url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes

Is it possible to have a action method with a name that is different to the action name specified in the url?  I tried doing this with the routes table in Global.asax with no luck.  Here's what I tried:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "ApproveSellers",
               "Admin/Account/ApproveSellers/",
               new { controller = "Account", action = "ApproveSeller"},
               new[] { "UI.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
```

I want the action method to be called ApproveSeller but the url to be ApproveSellers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it using action attribute. In the route, you just define the **default** value.

Here is in the controller:

```
public class AccountController

    [ActionName("ApproveSellers")]
    public ActionResult ApproveSeller
    {

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [attribute for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6536559/60761):

```
    [ActionName("NewName")]
    public ActionResult OldName()
    {
        return View();   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon, you may want to try and look at using the ActionName Attrribute, Phil Haack has a good article [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx) that you may want to take a look at.