# Ambiguous in Actions in asp.net mvc, how to resolve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two methods:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    return Redirect("/View/" + this.GetMenuItems().First().Id);
}

public ActionResult Index(int id, uint? limit)
{
```

when i go to **/View/1** - i get that error

*he current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'ViewController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]) on type SVNViewer.Controllers.ViewController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, System.Nullable`1[System.UInt32]) on type SVNViewer.Controllers.ViewController*

**I need that two methods but remove Ambiguous error, how can i do that?**

Comment: Rename one of the methods to something else: The second method to Index -> MenuItem perhaps?  Or, make the limit parameter required (not nullable) in the second.

Comment: @Tommy I would have given a vote if you replied that as an answer

Comment: @Mark - I appreciate that, but I didn't have enough time to formulate a good answer when I came across this, but wanted to throw in my 2 cents for testCoder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your second Action to not have an nullable uint.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, uint limit)
```

Your `Index(int? id)` should be the method which handles if limit is null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ActionName to work around this: [Purpose of ActionName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536559/purpose-of-actionname)

If both do the same thing, you can do instead:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, uint? limit = null)
{
  ...
}
```

Make the second parameter optional.

Or have one have [HttpGet] attribute and one have [HttpPost], if one responds to a get and the other responds to a posted form.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a model and have only one action method:

```
public class MyActionModel 
{
    public int? Id { get;set; }
    public int? Limit { get;set; }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyActionModel model)
{
    // Your code here
    if (model.Id.HasValue() { // do something....etc}
}
```