# Controller Methods with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods, controller, redirecttoaction

I have this method who call 2 others methods but i've an error when a execute that code.

```
public ActionResult CreateOrder(string action, string type)
    {
        /*Some Code*/
        if(MyObject.isOk){
            return RedirectToAction("EditOrder", new { code = ErrorCode, libelle = Description });

        }else{
            return RedirectToAction("EditOrder", new { nordre = NoOrdre });
        }
    }

public ActionResult EditOrder(string nordre)
    {

    }

[ActionName("EditOrder")]
public ActionResult EditOrderError(string code, string libelle)
{

    }
```

But i get an 404 because the script try to find the "EditOrderError" view.

Comment: How do you call this method from View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't allow you to [overload controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/436866/26396) *unless* they [handle different HTTP verbs](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx).

Assuming you're using C# 4, one possible workaround, albeit not a pretty one, is to use optional parameters on a single controller action:

```
public ActionResult EditOrder(string nordre = null, string code = null, string libelle = null)
{
    if (nordre != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (code != null && libelle != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload controller actions using the same HTTP Method/Verb (GET/POST/ etc)

I would only use `ActionNameAttribute` if I need the controller action to have characters that .NET doesn't allow in an identifier. Like using dashes (/controller/create-user). [Like this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6536789).