# CreatedAtRoute with template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a question. 
How to correctly create `CreatedAtRoute` to this Method:

```
HttpGet("exchangepoint")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ExchangePointDto), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetExchangePoint(string name)
```

I have tried like this:

```
result = CreatedAtRoute("GetExchangePoint",new { controller = "ShippingPlaceData", action = "GetExchangePoint", name = exchangePointToReturn.CustAccount }, exchangePointToReturn);
```

But it didn't work.

**Edit:**
When I changed `CreatedAtRoute` to `CreatedAtAction` it started work but it's correct way to do this?

Comment: See if [this](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.CreatedAtRoute(string,%20object,%20object)/) helps.

Comment: @RajeshG after when i changed to CreatedAtAction it stated work but i'm not sure it is correct way.

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839278/asp-net-core-rc2-web-api-post-when-to-use-create-createdataction-vs-created) helps you to decide.

Comment: @Newer For `CreatedAtRoute` a *route name* is needed. The target action does not have a route name. ie: `[HttpGet("exchangepoint", Name = "GetExchangePoint")]`

Comment: @RajeshG thank, i will look on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CreatedAtRoute` method - as you're using attribute routing, you need to specify the route name, like this.

```
[HttpGet("exchangepoint", Name = "GetExchangePoint")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ExchangePointDto), 200)]
public IActionResult GetExchangePoint(string name)
{

}
```

And in the post method, you can use like this.

```
result = CreatedAtRoute("GetExchangePoint",new { controller = "ShippingPlaceData", action = "GetExchangePoint", name = exchangePointToReturn.CustAccount }, exchangePointToReturn);
```

Comment: Thank, when i added Name = "GetExchangePoint" it started work