# Swagger UI response type returns Status (400) 400BadRequest, instead of (201) Status201Created but the record was inserted successfully

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to get the **201 status** response after a record is inserted successfully into the database but for some strange reasons i keep getting **400 status** but a record is in the db

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer)
{
   await _customerRepository.AddCustomer(client);
   return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetCustomerById), new { id = customer.Id }, customer);
}
```

and this one as well doesn't work

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer)
{
   await _customerRepository.AddCustomer(client);
   return new CreatedAtRouteResult("Get", new { id = customer.Id }, customer);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use breakpoints to test the method in `await _customerRepository.AddCustomer(client);`  there is no exception, and then provide `GetCustomerById` or `Get` methods for our reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
 [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
 public async Task<ActionResult> CreateCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer)
 {
   await _customerRepository.AddCustomer(client);
   return new CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = customer.Id }, customer);
 }
```

[ASP.net Core RC2 Web API POST - When to use Create, CreatedAtAction, vs. CreatedAtRoute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839278/asp-net-core-rc2-web-api-post-when-to-use-create-createdataction-vs-created)