# CreatedAtRoute: No route matches with empty route values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm currently struggling with CreatedAtRoute, below are the details.

Desired solution in the future

Return object and URI in location header linking to endpoint `GetGlobalSettings`.

Current situation and problem
I have the following POST endpoint for resource creation which returns CreatedAtRoute like this `return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetGlobalSettings), result.Data);`

The route set in the location header should link to the endpoint with this method head:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<GlobalSettingDto>> GetGlobalSettings()
```

With this I always get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Content-Type: application/json
:authority: localhost:5001
:method: POST
:path: /api/v1/GlobalSettings
:scheme: https
Accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Host: localhost:5001
Referer: https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.48
DNT: 1
Origin: https://localhost:5001
Content-Length: 768
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

I have API-versioning active, so I also tried the `CreatedAtRoute`-call like this:

```
var routeValues = new { version = "1.0" };
return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetGlobalSettings), routeValues, result.Data);
```

But this still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should use `CreatedAtAction`:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetGlobalSettings), routeValues, result.Data);
```

Regarding the difference between `CreatedAtAction` and `CreatedAtRoute`, you can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839278/asp-net-core-rc2-web-api-post-when-to-use-create-createdataction-vs-created).