# Using structureMap sample package in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I use both of MVC and WebApi in my application. For implementing IoC i use structure map sample package([StructureMap.WebApi2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.WebApi2/))

In MVC controllers everything is ok but when i use web api, for example post something to server i get this error:

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/api/Activity/AddActivity&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This is AddActivity action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("AddActivity")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddActivity(ActivityDTO activityDTO)
  {
      ActivityDTO data = activityDTO;
      HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

      data.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

      int id = _activityServices.Add(data);

      if (id != -1)
      {
         response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
      }
      else
      {
         response=this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Activity doesn't save.");
      }

       return response;
  }
```

I check the path of action and it's correct.

can you help me?

thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

***WebApiConfig.cs***

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        var container = IoCFactory.Container;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
            typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new IoCWebApiControllerFactory(container));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ControllerActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ControllerApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

***AjaxRequest:***

```
$.post("/api/Activity/AddActivity", data)
```

Comment: Have you tried this method: https://www.dotnettips.info/courses/topic/5/3697d84b-8c79-4722-875f-a35920fe88ba

Comment: @VahidN Thanks for replay and your useful topics at dotnettips.info...I implement IoC as you explain but it gets error while using web api controllers...I post a new question about it : [using-structuremap-with-mvc-and-webapi-together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988619/using-structuremap-with-mvc-and-webapi-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not the dependency injection. Put a break-point on the constructor and check if the injected dependencies are not null. If those are not null, your setup is correct.

You have routing issues. When you are using `[ActionName("AddActivity")]` you should have a routing defined like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "ActionApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
```

The default `routeTemplate` of web-api doesn't have the `{action}` part. Also you shouldn't use `ActionName` here, because [it has a different purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536559/purpose-of-actionname/6536978). Replace it with the `Route` attribute to use the `attribute routing` capabilities. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563099/webapi-actionname-routing-half-working)

Comment: I change the **[ActionName("AddActivity")]** to **[Route("AddActivity")]** but i get an exception in **GetControllerInstance** method...it says **Page not found: /api/Activity/AddActivity**...i change the request path,route attribute and web api config template but nothing happened and i get that error again.i put the ajax request code in question.

Comment: When you are using attribute routing your "/api" won't be used anymore. Start learning about attribute routing here https://www.dotnettips.info/post/1660

Comment: Thank you...I'm beginner in MVC and this is very helpful.