# Swagger-Net Shows controller name instead of endpoint method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I've been trying to figure out why Swagger-Net does not show the endpoint methods in a controller.

[image: How it looks when Swagger references only the controller]

[image: The endpoint method looks like this]

The C# project is using a Web API template based on .Net framework 4.6.1.

I get the same result when I use SwashBuckler, so it's not Swagger-Net that's the issue, but something that is not configured or missing.

The SwaggerConfig looks like this

```cs
    public class SwaggerConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", nameof(ConsentResponseApp));

                    c.AccessControlAllowOrigin("*");

                  c.IncludeAllXmlComments(thisAssembly, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                 c.UImaxDisplayedTags(100);

                    c.UIfilter("''");
                    });
    }
  }
```

I'm at a dead end at the moment since I have no idea why Swagger cannot read the methods action names.

### The answer:

The WebApiConfig route is not by default configured to route with action

```cs
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

it has to be changed to

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

[image: With the {action} parameter added]

Comment: Have you enabled XML documentation in your web api project's properties?

Comment: I think you need a route, not actionname; besides that it is advised you also add your responses. :   [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK", typeof(User))]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error", typeof(string))]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Notfound", typeof(string))]
        [Route("SaveConsent")]
        [HttpPost]

Comment: Changing the route was the key.

The route looked like this at WebApiConfig.cs

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


Needed to change it to 

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Where the {action} was added between the controller and id

Comment: @leon Put an answer so I can give you the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a route, not an actionname

```
[Route("SaveConsent")]
```

Besides that, it is advisable to add expected responses like so:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK", typeof(User))] [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error", typeof(string))] [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Notfound", typeof(string))] 
[Route("SaveConsent")] 
[HttpPost]
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Leon's comment. You need to specify a Route as Leon showed above.

I'm not sure `[ActionName()]` is what you need at all since it will allow your API's consumer to specify the URI with characters .NET may not allow or using a different signature than your actual controller method.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536559/purpose-of-actionname) post for the reason behind `[ActionName()]`.

Comment: Not sure who to give the point to, since Leon was first, but he wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I will gladly remove my answer once Leon has posted his one and then you can accept it.