# AspNet MVC Web Api, ActionName or Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Having the Method/Action *ObtainValue*, I want to assign a different name to the method when it is called, so I use the *ActionName* attribute

```
    [ActionName("GetValueByID")]
    public string ObtainValue(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

But I can also use the *Route* attribute, as shown below

```
    [Route("Api/Values/GetValueByID")]
    public string ObtainValue(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

So my question is, is there a difference?, should use one or the other? what about if I use both, which one takes precedence?

Comment: Here is a good explanation of `ActionName`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536559/purpose-of-actionname

Answer (score 5):

ActionName : is action (resource-specific) name to the method..Intention is to give user friendly name to the particular method eg. FetchEmployeeData to GetEmployee...you can't specify controller name for prefix with "actionname"

Route : is the define fully qualified URL (more generic) to the URL-Pattern
....it is use to understand full resource path to user...with "Route" you can specify controller name separated by "/"..same as when specify fully qualified URL route in maproute method in routeconfig

In simple words we can say that, "ActionName" is used for particular method(resource), and 
other side we use "Route" to define URL-Pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActionName` attribute to override the method name in API URL, and `Route` attribute to override the whole API URL.